# vlc 2.2.6-6 was working, now will not open most DVD

Tags: vlc, dvd, restricted-formats

vlc 2.2.6-6 was working, now will not open most DVD 
Like "The Twillight Zone the 5th Demension" and it did right after installing the OS

```bash
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:        17.10
Codename:       artful
```

```bash
dpkg --get-selections | grep vlc >> VLC-maybe_fix.odt
libvlc-bin:amd64                install
libvlc5:amd64                   install
libvlccore8:amd64               install
vlc                             install
vlc-bin                         install
vlc-data                        install
vlc-l10n                        install
vlc-plugin-base:amd64           install
vlc-plugin-notify:amd64         install
vlc-plugin-qt:amd64             install
vlc-plugin-samba:amd64          install
vlc-plugin-skins2:amd64         install
vlc-plugin-video-output:amd64   install
vlc-plugin-video-splitter:amd64 install
vlc-plugin-visualization:amd64  install
```

Comment: Could you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/986049/edit) your question to add the output of `lsb_release -a`. - [From review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/785865)

Comment: is `libdvdcss-pkg` installed?

Comment: i get E: unable to locate package libdvdcss-pkg

Comment: The correct package name is `libdvd-pkg`.